# How to extract rows which contains data on a particular length position in Unix

Tags: unix

I need to know if there is a data on a particular position in a text file in Unix, if yes than I need to copy those rows in another file. For example if I have a text file and I need to know is there is data on position number 1600 (length 12), if there is data starting from position 1600 to 1612, I need to copy those rows in another text file. Can someone help in Unix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please indicate what you have already tried  or (at least) researched to come up with the solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
sed -ne '/^.\{1612\}/p' input.txt >> output.txt
```

The pattern `.\{1612\}` means 1612 of any character. Only lines that have this many characters will match, such lines will be printed to standard output, which you can redirect to another file, in this example to `output.txt`.